# PHPExcel namespace issue in PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWrite()

Tags: php, namespaces, phpexcel

I have a question regarding namespaces and PHPExcel. Current I have a class called ExportToExcel in namespace Portal\Helpers. This class builds the excel file and calls the PHPExcel class. However I keep getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWrite()
```

In ExportToExcel I call PHPExcel via:

```
$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel;
```

After building the sheet I call:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWrite($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
```

And here the error is generated. Everyting is going ok until this line.

I do not use an existing framework. Recently I've built in namespaces in my project and beforehand it was working ok. So I wonder if anyone of you came across the same issue or knows the answer to my problem?

I use PHPExcel 1.8.0. And did found some topics with existing frameworks (e.g. Symfony and Zend) and the 'same' namespace proble, however I could not find a proper solution to my problem.

Answer (score 3):

The method is

```
createWriter();
           ^
 Note the "r" at the end
```

not

```
createWrite();
```

and nothing whatsoever to do with namespaces

Comment: Thank you sir. Possibly due to frustration I could not see this huge mistake. After defining "use PHPExcel_IOFactory;" at the top of the class everything is working properly.